# MVVM Issues with Kotlin - Getting some error with modularization

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

## Objective:

I would like to modularize my code, but I am not well familiarized with Kotlin/Java -- considerable new to both languages, I was coding with React Native.

The following code is how I was making the model-view implementation. If anyone has a better suggestion in how to make a MVVM.

I try to do direct access as in the following code and I try to create instances of the CustomerModel() and CustomerActivity(), but it gives a black blank screen.

This **CustomerModel** will be responsible to connect to the Customer Database using firebase.

The **CustomerActivity** will ask to save info, load info and it will display infos using result form database consulting.

There will be other activities accessing CustomerModel (such settings activity, list view activity, ...)

How can I make this code working and better to be handling all Database stuff outside the View?

## Issues:

The **hasInfo** is not being update. It is always false, and checking the Database is true for my test user

I received this error, I must be doing some mistake, but can't find out what:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet
>   attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which
>   usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is
>   attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).

Apparently is happening on tring to update the TextView and the ImageView, maybe there is not created yet(my guess)

## CustomerModel.kt (Model)

```
private lateinit var mCustomerDatabase: DatabaseReference

internal fun getUserInfo(uid: String) {
  mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child("Customers").child(uid)

  mCustomerDatabase.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.childrenCount > 0) {
        val map: (Map < String, Any > ) = dataSnapshot.value as(Map < String, Any > )

        if (map["profileImageUrl"] != null) {
          Glide.with(CustomerActivity().application).load(map["profileImageUrl"].toString()).into(CustomerActivity().mNavigationHeaderImage)
        }

        if (map["name"] != null) {
          CustomerActivity().mNavigationHeaderText.text = map["name"].toString()
        }

        if (map["hasCarInfo"] != null) {
          CustomerActivity().hasInfo = map["hasInfo"].toString().toBoolean()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

## CustomerActivity.kt (View and Activity)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)

   (...)

   // load all UI settings
   handleUI()

   // Update User Info
   CustomerDatabase().getUserInfo(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
}

override fun onStart(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onStart()
   (...)
   // Update User Info
   CustomerDatabase().getUserInfo(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
}
```

**mNavigationHeaderImage** is imported from xml (ImageView)

**mNavigationHeaderText** is imported from xml (TextView)

**hasInfo** is a var that is used to check if the user has info or need to fetch by default is false

Comment: `CustomerActivity()`, this is not how you access an activity.

Comment: MVVM follows the **seperation of concern** and you have confused business login with your views and model.kt, like you did model class doesn't responsible for business logic model.kt should be like your _Resume_ name age etc.. repository will be handling either your skills are enough to fill up company criteria, viewModel will be sort of like ur body language and progress from repository(class) in company and activity will be your personality, your appearance. You dont need to mix all these to each other. If you do MVVM properly most of the things will be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your `getUserInfo` you try to update some text fileds of your `activity` using following notion

```
CustomerActivity().mNavigationHeaderText.text = map["name"].toString()
```

Problematic thing is that you are trying to create `instance` of your `activity` using `CustomerActivity()`. This is wrong, because in `Android` `Instance` of `activities` are created by the `Android` `SDK`.

***So how do you use `instance` of your `activity`?***

As you probably know `activities` has a certain [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), So after creating `instance` of your `activity` and `initialization`, `Android` calls `lifecycle functions` such as `onCreate` and `onRestart`, in those functions ***`this`*** refers to your activity's `instance`.

***Ultimate solution to your problem*** is the [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) to learn about `LiveData`.

Following are two alternate solutions, both of these will work but if you can configure your project to use `LiveData` then avoid the following.

To solve your problem, ***a simple yet wrong thing would be*** to do the following, here you pass the `instance` of `activity` as a `parameter` to `getUserInfo`

```
CustomerDatabase().getUserInfo(this, mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
```

Second approach would be to use `callback interface`. so in your activity define an interface as following

```
interface Callback {
   fun onFinished(map: Map <String, Any> )
}
```

Now modify your `activity` to implement this `interface`, so in your `activity` you will have a function as following

```
onFinished(map: Map <String, Any> ){
    // use map to set your data
}
```

After this modify your `getUserInfo` to take a parameter of type Callback, and this callback will be called by getUserInfo when it gets data.

```
internal fun getUserInfo(uid: String, callback: Callback) {
  mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child("Customers").child(uid)
  mCustomerDatabase.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.childrenCount > 0) {
          val map: (Map < String, Any > ) = dataSnapshot.value as(Map < String, Any > )
          /** When data is available, pass it to activity by calling the callback */
          callback.onFinished(map);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: How may I call the callback using getUserInfo?